# Apple touch icon not working

Tags: html, apple-touch-icon

I am writing an html5 game, and trying to get an apple touch icon to work. I am testing on a non-retina iPhone 4S running ios5.  The first part of my html file is:

```
<head>

<title>My Game</title>

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```

I am also using a [script](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) to prompt users to add the touch icon; this script shows a preview of the touch icon, and it finds the icon with no problem.  Also, the icon is [public](http://tapoutdemo.atwebpages.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png), not password-protected.

When I add the shortcut to my home screen, I get the simple screenshot icon.  I have tried clearing my history and cache.  Am I doing something wrong?  Are those no-cache meta tags interfering with the icon?  (They are there so I don't have to worry about caching issues while developing.)

Comment: I get an HTTP Error 500 on that icon caused by a malfunctioning 403 handler, which probably explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: I just noticed that.  When I visit the site, and view source, I can click on the icon link and see the image.  There is no password-protection at all on the site.  The site is http://tapoutdemo.atwebpages.com/tapout_game.html

Comment: Nope, I don't see it. You may want to flush your cache or try it from another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came down to the fact that my hosting provider does not allow hotlinking of images.  So I set up an account at imgur.com, hosted the touch icon there, and it works.  I was happy to see that an externally-hosted touch icon works.